# Android send email with multiple attachments issues

Tags: android, email, email-attachments, send

I was able to send email with single attachment. When I switch to send email with multiple attachment, the send mail code doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
 private void ShareViaEmail(String csvFilePath, String ibiFilePath, String message, String mailTo) {
    try {
        //File Root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //String fileLocation=Root.getAbsolutePath() + folderName + "/" + fileName;
        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

        //attach multiple file
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

        intent.setType("text/plain");
        //String message="CSV file is " + csvFilePath + ".";
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Report ");
        //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse( "file://"+csvFilePath));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ibiFilePath : "+ibiFilePath );
        //attached multiple file
        //followed by:
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(csvFilePath)));
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(ibiFilePath)));

        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + mailTo));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception e)  {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"exception raises during sending mail"+e );
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors message.
2019-08-18 11:19:56.736 2979-2979/com.xyz.testemail W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.TEXT expected ArrayList but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value  was returned.
2019-08-18 11:19:56.741 2979-2979/com.xyz.testemail W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getCharSequenceArrayList(BaseBundle.java:1265)
        at android.os.Bundle.getCharSequenceArrayList(Bundle.java:1075)
        at android.content.Intent.getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(Intent.java:7919)
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:10774)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1617)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4621)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4579)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4940)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4908)
        at com.xyz.testemail.MainActivity.ShareViaEmail(MainActivity.java:508)

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
```

If you are using `EXTRA_STREAM`, you're not supposed to also use `EXTRA_TEXT`. And, for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, `EXTRA_TEXT` needs to be a `List` of strings, not a single string.

Also:

- Your code will crash on Android 7.0+, because you are using `Uri.forFile()`. Use `FileProvider` to make your content available to the other app.
- No email app has to support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`
- Other apps can support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, not just email apps

Comment: If I remove intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); where can I insert the email body text ?

Comment: @CK8: I have not used `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, let alone with an email client. You would need to run some tests with popular email clients (Gmail, K-9 Mail, FastMail, ProtonMail, etc.) and see what they do.

Comment: I remove   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message) line and change the following line but I still getting exception change to 

    uris.add(Uri.parse("file://"+csvFilePath));
    uris.add(Uri.parse("file://"+ibiFilePath));

Comment: @CK8: If you removed `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)`, you will be getting a different exception. Examine the updated stack trace.

Comment: I am getting this exception -   raises during sending mailandroid.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/testfile.csv now.

Comment: @CK8: I commented on that in my answer: "Your code will crash on Android 7.0+, because you are using `Uri.forFile()`. Use `FileProvider` to make your content available to the other app."